# How to split each entry of an array on each whitespace?

Tags: perl

I have a file like this:

```
This is is my "test"
file with a lot
words separeted by whitespace.
```

Now I want to achieve to split this so that i create an array where each element contains of one word and all duplicate words are deleted

the desired array:

```
This
is
my
test
etc...
```

I read the file into an array but I do not know how to split an whole array so that the result is a new array. And how can I remove the duplicate words?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
package catalogs;
use  Log::Log4perl;
Log::Log4perl->init("log4perl.properties");


open(FILE, "<Source.txt") || die "file Sources.txt konnte nicht geoeffnet werden";

my @fileContent = <FILE>;
close FILE;

my $log = Log::Log4perl->get_logger("catalogs");

@fileContent = split(" ");
```

Answer (score 2):

To extract the words, you could use

```
my @words = $str =~ /\w+/g;
```

As for removing duplicates,

```
use List::MoreUtils qw( uniq );
my @uniq_words = uniq @words;
```

or

```
my %seen;
my @uniq_words = grep !$seen{$_}++, @words;
```

Comment: Can you explain you extract method a bit? what is $str? I have read the file into an array name @fileContent, did you mean this array instead of $str?

Comment: The string from which you want to extract the words. Arrays don't contain words.

Comment: ...If you want to search all the strings in the array, do that. Or don't use an array you don't need in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You're loading the text of the file into an array, but it may make more sense to load the file into a single string. This would enable you to take advantage of the solution @ikegami provided. To bring it all together, try the following.

```
use List::MoreUtils qw( uniq );
my $filecontent = do
{
  local $/ = undef;
  <STDIN>;
};
my @words = $filecontent =~ /\w+/g;
my @uniqword = uniq(@words);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my $log = Log::Log4perl->get_logger("catalogs");
@fileContent = split(/\s+/, $log); 
@filecontent = uniq(@filecontent);
```

To make the words unique, you can use `uniq` subroutine or map it into a `hash`. Since keys of a hash are always unique, duplicates will be over-written.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @a = (1,1,1,2,3,4,4);
my %hash = ();
%hash = map $_=>'1', @a;
my @new = keys(%hash );
print Dumper(@new);
```